# Select or print column values that don’t exist between two integers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of about 10k sequential integer values that were supposed to be inserted into a table column from an external application. However, doing a COUNT() reveals that only 9900 were inserted.

I need to determine which of the numbers in the sequence were NOT inserted.

Using it the other way around is easy, just select from table column where value is BETWEEN x AND y, but I haven't figured out how to print (or select) the values that don't exist in the table column.

*EDIT: remove extranous '' from integers below*

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column1 = 'value'
AND column2 BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

How can I print the value from the BETWEEN clause where column2 doesn't have value in range?

Comment: Expected output is 4444, 6789, etc

Comment: Are you using oracle?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Oracle

Comment: Don't specify numbers as strings. `'1'` is a string constant, `1` would be a number. And when it comes to comparison, `'10'` is smaller than `'2'`, whereas `10` is bigger than `2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
select level num
from   dual
connect by level <= 10000
minus
select column2
from   your_table;
```

You may need to do `to_char(level)` if your column2 is a varchar2 column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a source of numbers.  If this table is your only data, you can use it:

```
with n as (
      select rownum as n
      from t cross join
           (select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual) x
     )
select n.n
from n left join
     t
     on n.n = t.column2 and t.column1 = 'value'
where n <= 10000;
```

The calculation for `n` assumes that your table has at least 5,000 rows.  If it has more than 10,000 then `x` is not necessary.